# swashbuckle document csrf token. how to pass it? document it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I am using swashbuckle to document my webapi 2.0 api. it's basicaly ok and it's enough for my use case, but there is something that I can't handle. 
CFRS - well - there is not much resources about webapi and CSRF, but i thing it's impotant to have this kind of protection. 
So I have implemented it by custom header. and now i just cant use my swagger ui - becouse of that. It would be great to pass some header value in UI. is it even possible? please Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the class itself is not realy good documented, but I have added my ownn class in swagger.config.cs

```
c.OperationFilter<CsrfDocumentFiler>();
```

and implemented it like this:

```
public class CsrfDocumentFiler: IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(Operation operation, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, ApiDescription apiDescription)
    {
        if (operation.operationId != "Token_GetToken")
        {
            if (operation.parameters == null)
                operation.parameters = new List<Parameter>();

            operation.parameters.Add(new Parameter
            {
                name = "__RequestVerificationToken",
                @in = "header",
                type = "string",
                required = true
            });
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to filter for all operation for a particular verb and use OperationFilterContext

```
c.OperationFilter<CsrfOperationFilter>();



public class CsrfOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Applies the specified operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="operation">The operation.</param>
    /// <param name="context">The context.</param>
    public void Apply(Operation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        if (string.Equals(context.ApiDescription.HttpMethod, "Get", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            return;
        }

        if (operation.Parameters == null)
        {
            operation.Parameters = new List<IParameter>();
        }

        operation.Parameters.Add(new NonBodyParameter
        {
            Name = "csrf_token",
            In = "header",
            Type = "string",
            Required = true,
        });
    }
}
```